# Extraer datos de Oracle y Insertar registros en sqlServer 2012 con c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Amigo les hago la siguiente consulta.

1. quiero extraer datos de una tabla de oracle para lo cual ocupo el siguiente método.

   public ActionResult GetContrato(int id) {

   ```
       OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();

       //db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
       var mfallo = db.MtoFallo.Where(f => f.MtoRequerimientoId == id).FirstOrDefault();

       var sql = @"select  to_char(a.fecha_terminacion,'yyyy') as Ejercicio,
                   b.gpo,b.gen,b.esp,b.dif,b.var,a.no_contrato,a.monto_original,a.monto_contrato,a.monto_minimo,a.no_licitacion,
                   C.EVENTO_COMPRANET,
                   A.ESTADO_CONTRATO,a.rfc_proveedor,                       
                   B.CANT_MAX,
                   B.CANT_MIN,
                   B.CANT_MAX * B.PRECIO_NETO as MontoPartida,
                   B.CANT_AUM,
                   B.CANTIDAD_EJERCIDA,
                   B.PRECIO_CLAVE,
                   B.DESCUENTO,
                   B.PRECIO_NETO,
                   A.FECHA_EMISION
                   , A.FECHA_INICIO,
                   a.fecha_terminacion,
                   a.fecha_firma,B.STATUS
                   from adq_mcontratos a
                   left join adq_clave_contrato b on a.no_contrato=b.no_contrato
                   left join adq_nolicita_compranet c on TRIM(a.no_licitacion)=TRIM(C.NO_LICITACION)";

       if (mfallo != null)
       {
           sql = sql + " where  c.NO_LICITACION='" + mfallo.MtoProcedimientos.NoLicitacion + "'";
       }

       if (mfallo !=null) {

           try
           {

               OracleConnection Con = new OracleConnection(TNS);
               Con.Open();
               DataTable tab = new DataTable();
               OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, Con);
               da.Fill(tab);                                      
               Con.Close();
               Con.Dispose();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               conn.Close();
               //command.Dispose();
               conn.Dispose();
               conn = null;
               ex.ToString();
           }                              

       }
       return Json(mfallo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       //return Json(mfallo);            

   }
   ```

hasta aquí todo bien ahora lo que quiero es insertar aquellos registros que no existan en mi base de datos de SQLSERVER 2018, esto con visual studio 2017 y c#

creen poder echarme la mano

Comment: Nunca concatenes datos a tus consultas ya que son susceptibles a SQL Injection, siempre es recomendable usar consultas parametrizadas

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un `DataTable` con los datos de `Oracle` puedes insertarlos en `Sql Server` usando:

[Bulk Insert records and Update existing rows if record exists using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy--Bulk-Insert-records-and-Update-existing-rows-if-record-exists-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

La idea es crear un procedure donde definas el `MERGE` de sql

[MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)

```
  MERGE INTO Customers c1
  USING @tblCustomers c2
  ON c1.CustomerId=c2.Id
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET c1.Name = c2.Name
        ,c1.Country = c2.Country
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT VALUES(c2.Id, c2.Name, c2.Country);
```

en este caso hace uso de un tabla como tipo al usar

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CustomerType] AS TABLE(
```

entonces desde codigo puede pasar el `DataTable` por parametro al procedure

```
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update_Customers"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblCustomers", dt);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Es importante entender que esta usando `Table-Valued Parameters`, de esta forma no necesitas iterar cada row del datatable para insertar, la pasas directo.

[Parámetros con valores de tabla](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Asi el `procedure` se encarga de aplicar el `MERGE` sobre los datos inserando o actualizando segun corresponda